# Evento CSS al pulsar sobre contenedor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una imagen y estoy tratando de que al darle click encima me haga un efecto flip que ya tengo realizado y me de vuelta la imagen. La cuestión es que lo he manejado con over y con active. Pero uno me lo hace cuando tengo el raton encima de la imagen y el otro cuando pulso sobre la imagen, y tengo que tener el raton pulsado encima de la imagen mientras hace toda la transicion.

Mi idea es que cuando pulse una imagen de una carta me de vuelta a la carta y se muestre. Y cuando la pulse de nuevo vuelva a su estado origen. y no se si puedo tratar esto via css.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfcbM.jpg

```
.flip:active {
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-180deg) translateX(100%);
}
```

flip es la clase que tienen los contenedores de las cartas de la imagen

¿Hay alguna propiedad css como el onclick?

Comment: Me temo que tendrás que utilizar javascript

Comment: perfecto, y sabes algo al respecto o que deberia utilizar?

Comment: Por que no subes el código de toda la estructura html que tienes para esa parte en concreto ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes añadirle una clase al elemento al hacer click sobre él.

Hay diferentes formas de hacerlo. Utilizando jQuery podrías utilizar, por ejemplo, el método `toggleClass` de forma que el primer click añadiese la clase y el siguiente la eliminase devolviendo el elemento a su estado original:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.card').click(function(){ $(this).toggleClass('flip'); });
});
```

```css
.card{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  left: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.flip {
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-180deg) translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">carta a rotar</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda compañero

Answer (score 5):

No necesariamente necesitas JavaScript para hacer lo que requieres en tu pregunta, puedes hacerlo con CSS de la siguiente forma:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label img{
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-180deg) translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="imagen" id="imagen">
<label for="imagen">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TRGwus4.png" alt="Imagen" id="img">
</label>
```

Es un pequeño truco que podrías utilizar en caso de que no quieras usar JavaScript o sus librerías.

Comment: Buena alternativa

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Fijate si te sirve esta librería, https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Saludos.

Comment: Muy buena libreria ;D